# Merge two objects and increase the keys in ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I want to merge several objects together, but because their keys are equal, when using `Object.assign()` it just returns the same properties as the last one.

```
let obj1 = {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "d"};
let obj2 = {0: "e", 1: "f", 2: "g", 3: "h"};
```

But the output that I want

```
let output = {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "d", 4: "e", 5: "f", 6: "g", 7: "h"};
```

Comment: How did you try to merge them both?

Comment: Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really just use arrays for this. It would make your life easier.

Having said that, you can take the `values` from the objects, which will be arrays, concat them, and then make a new object with:

```js
let obj1 = {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "d"}
let obj2 = {0: "e", 1: "f", 2: "g", 3: "h"}

let obj = Object.values(obj1).concat(Object.values(obj2))
          .reduce((a, c, i) => (a[i] = c, a), {})
console.log(obj)
```

You can also use spread syntax with:

```js
let obj1 = {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "d"}
let obj2 = {0: "e", 1: "f", 2: "g", 3: "h"}

let obj = {...Object.values(obj1).concat(Object.values(obj2))}
console.log(obj)
```

It's ambiguous what should happen with a case like this:

```
let obj1 = {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 4: "d"}
let obj2 = {0: "e", 1: "f", 2: "g", 3: "h"}
```

Comment: Note that neither object spread nor `Object.values` are ECMAScript 6.

Answer (score 2):

If the keys are numerical, convert both objects to arrays by using `Object.assign([], obj)` (or `Object.values(obj)`, though that’s *not ES6*), `concat` them, then put all enumerable properties into a new object by using `Object.assign`:

```js
const obj1 = {
      0: "a",
      1: "b",
      2: "c",
      3: "d"
    },
  obj2 = {
      0: "e",
      1: "f",
      2: "g",
      3: "h"
    },
  output = Object.assign({}, Object.assign([], obj1).concat(Object.assign([], obj2)));

console.log(output);
```

Although, if the numerical key assumption holds, consider just skipping the final `Object.assign`. The properties will all be the same, plus some useful array methods and properties (the enumerable properties will match exactly).

Answer (score 2):

You could concat an arbitrary count of objects by concatenation of all values and assign them back to an object.

```js
let obj1 = { 0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c", 3: "d" },
    obj2 = { 0: "e", 1: "f", 2: "g", 3: "h" },
    merged = Object.assign({}, [obj1, obj2].reduce((r, o) => r.concat(Object.values(o)), []));
    
console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of the objects and use reduce method.Pass an empty object as `thisArg` and keep an `index` which will increase and this `index` will act as a key.Inside the reduce method use `Object.values` which will give an array all the values of the current object like `[a,b,c,d]`. Now iterate this array and update the blank object which was initially passed

```js
let obj1 = {
  0: "a",
  1: "b",
  2: "c",
  3: "d"
};
let obj2 = {
  0: "e",
  1: "f",
  2: "g",
  3: "h"
};
let comObj = [obj1, obj2]
let index = 0;
let mrgObj = comObj.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let getVals = Object.values(curr);
  getVals.forEach(function(item, currIndex) {
    acc[index] = item
    index++;
  })
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(mrgObj)
```